# Find classes within Jar

Tags: java, unix, class, jar

I have a jar file and I want to know which all classes are within it. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`jar`](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/view.html)

```
jar tf jar-file
```

- The `t` option indicates that you want
  to view the table of contents of the
  JAR file.
- The `f` option indicates that the JAR
  file whose contents are to be viewed
  is specified on the command line.
  Without the f option, the Jar tool
  would expect a filename on stdin.
- The `jar-file` argument is the filename
  (or path and filename) of the JAR
  file whose contents you want to view.

and if you want to list just the `.class` files you can filter the result using `grep` as:

```
jar tf jar-file | grep '\.class$'
```

Answer (score 2):

A jar file is just a fancy zip archive. You can use the classes in the [java.util.jar](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) package to read a jar file and traverse its contents, looking for .class files.